# variables are uninitialized C++

Tags: c++

```
int LeftClick(int xaxis ,int yaxis); 
{
    int xaxis;
    int yaxis;

    PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
    PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
}

LeftClick(720, 540);
```

I am tying to make a click function with python but for some reason i cant make it work as i always get an error that the variables are uninitialized since I'm new to c++ I'm not quite sure how to fix this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you declare `xaxis` and `yaxis` again, then?

Comment: You cannot have local variables with the same name as the method arguments.

Comment: @MDK Yes you can; you just shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid making same name, has already existed.

```
int LeftClick(int xaxis, int yaxis); // remove semicolon
{
  int xaxis; //xaxis exists already. you should make it different name
  int yaxis; //yaxis exists already. you should make it different name

  PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
  PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
}
```

If you want to use the given parameters,

you can use without re-declaring variables.

Here is my suggestion.

```
int LeftClick(int xaxis, int yaxis)
{
    PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
    PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
}
```

Comment: When i do that the MAKELPARAM gives an error of Undefined variable :/

Comment: ***MAKELPARAM gives an error of Undefined variable*** That should be defined in windows.h

Comment: @Pythonbeginner MAKELPARAM is the macro defined in Winuser.h. To solve the error, you should include windows.h because Winuser.h is included in windows.h. The explanation about MAKELPARAM is [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
int LeftClick(int x ,int y)
{
  int xaxis = x;
  int yaxis = y;

  PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
  PostMessage(hwndchild3, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(xaxis, yaxis));
}
```

Try that, you are declaring variables under the same name as the ones being passed and not assigning anything to the new ones. You could just get rid of the `int xaxis;` and `int yaxis;` inside the function all together.